# Import only history from CVS repository into already created git repository

Tags: git, github, version-control, cvs

At work we have a CVS repository that has commits stretching back nearly 15 years.  A couple of years ago that repository was converted to git and uploaded to a public GitHub repository.  However, the git repository was just initialized with the current version of the files, no history was imported (not my doing).  The CVS history is straightforward and linear--we never used CVS branches.  It is not a highly-active repository: there have been only about 25 commits to the public git repository since it was created.

I would like to be able to import the CVS history into the existing git repository without necessarily creating a new repository.  From what I've read in the documentation for `git-cvsimport` or `cvs2git`, those tools always create new repositories. Alternatively, I could do a fresh cvs/git conversion and upload the new repository in place of the current one, and apply the 25 post-cvs commits.  Is this possible, and if so, what is the recommended way to do this?  I have read & write access to both the CVS and git repositories, and server access to the CVS one if necessary.

I am fairly comfortable with simple git branching, merging, and rebasing, but I would not say I am an expert (I consult the Pro Git book a lot).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the solution is to create temporary branch ("start") from the first commit in the master branch, then generating and importing history from CSV into another temporary branch ("import"), merging with strategy ours from the "start" branch and merging from "master" branch the newer commits and renaming the "import" branch to "master":

```
# create new git repository by running cvs2git in import-git-path
# change directory to your current repository
git log
# find the first commit
git checkout -b start "first-commit"
git checkout --orphan branch
rm -rf * .gitignore # or any other file
git add -A
git remote add import-repo import-git-path
git pull import-repo master
git merge -s ours start
git merge master
git branch -D start
git branch -D master
git branch -m import master
```

Comment: Thanks for this response! Instead of `git branch import --orphan` I used `git checkout --orphan import`.  After that `git status` tells me that every file is "new", so that seems right.  When I try to do `git pull import-repo master`, it seems like the fetch goes OK, but the merge does not: I get: `error: Entry 'filename' would be overwritten by merge. Cannot merge.` After deleting and re-cloning the current repository and repeating, I get a different 'filename', so I think there is nothing special about that particular file.  Do I need to force the merge?

Comment: Sorry about the mistake with orphan. Did you follow the step `rm -rf * .gitignore # or any other file` , I.e. cleaning the working directory?

Comment: No worries, and yes.  `git status` shows 'changes to be committed' as 'new file: filenameA, new file: filenameB,' etc, and 'changes not staged for commit' as 'deleted: filenameA, deleted: filenameB', etc.  The repository directly is completely empty except for the ./.git folder.  I am wondering if that should be `git rm -rf` instead?

Comment: @Derek : Either this or `git add -A` should work as well. The goal is to have empty work tree.

Comment: Thanks again for the help.  Had to deal with some merge conflicts, and still have to deal with some oddities such as the same commit message for multiple different commits over a 4-year period, corresponding to every time a file was added to the CVS repo.  But that is either a CVS or a cvs2git problem, I don' think it is a git problem.